# In S02E40, why was Luci so attracted to Noman if there was no devil acting upon her?

Tags: plot-explanation, anger-management

In *Anger Management*, S2E40 (titled "Charlie and the Devil"), why was Luci so attracted to Noman if there was no devil acting upon her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're actually called Lacey and Nolan. And she was attracted to him because she was just on ecstasy. This is explained in the end:

> Bob: I'm not the devil.
>
> Nolan: Wait, this is amazing. I didn't sell my soul, which means Lacey really loves me.
>
> Lacey: Hey, sorry I'm late. I just slept for 18 hours. I bet my friend that I could do ecstasy five days in a row and it wouldn't affect my life and I totally won the bet.
>
> Nolan: Ecstasy? You said you were in love with me. You said my ass was adorable.
>
> Lacey: Wow, I did? Well, that didn't affect *my* life, so I still won the 50 bucks. Yay me.